# Orchard CMS build script - excluded module projects included in build

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using Orchard 1.6 and have a question regarding the build batch file.

When run, the script builds every module within the "Modules" directory, regardless of whether the module project is included in the VS solution.

Is there a setting somewhere so only module projects are built if the corresponding project is loaded in VS? (I'd like to prevent excluded/unloaded projects from being part of the build)

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the script so that it builds based on the solution instead of the orchard.proj file.